# Creating User Defined Table Type for multiple uses

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I commonly run into this issue at work, I'm a SQL developer. An app developer needs to pass in a table of data from their app into the DB to run in a proc because it would be more efficient than running a query in a loop for every row.

Generally the options are...if it's a single value, then shove it all into a single string, comma delimited, and then pass it into a large string parameter on the proc. In SQL we have a function that parses the string into a table and then works from there.

The other two options are to pass in XML and parse that in SQL. Or to use a User Defined Table Type and use a Table parameter on the proc.

Rather than creating all sorts of custom table types. I was thinking about creating a User Defined Table Type that just has a bunch of generically named columns, all of the columns being nullable and VARCHAR or NVARCHAR.

And then that single custom table type can be used in all places where app code needs to pass in a table of data into SQL to do some sort of processing.

I don't have much experience with app code (in this case were talking C#), so I don't know if maybe there's a better way to handle these situations? Or if my solution presents issues that make it more work than it's worth.

**Update:**
One thing I did not consider / just realized, was the hassle this would cause for the C# developer. Since they would need to "populate" the columns not needed.

Comment: Pretty vague and open ended but I would lean towards making an int table, a (n)varchar table or whatever datatypes. It could be really ugly in code to populate the table type with a bunch of columns that aren't needed. If int I would assume that is something like "find these values". But for character data I hope you aren't finding rows based on character data on a regular basis.

Comment: @SeanLange I know, it's pretty vague, but it's also a question for solving multiple problems with a generic solution. haha. In this particular case, it's a GUID and a Date value. In other cases, the data may vary. And yeah, I didn't really think about how they would handle the extra columns. In SQL it's easy, since you can just Declare the table as that type and just use the columns you need. I didn't think about the C# side, they would need to create a bunch of useless columns to pass in.

Comment: Exactly!!! You can easily create a GuidTable and a DateTable. Those can be used easily on both sides.

Comment: @SeanLange but how would you keep the GUID's and Date's paired together? The Identity?

Comment: I always use an xml structure because its easy to construct in the c# side and can be automatically deconstructed into a temp table in the stored proc. Much simpler that trying to do anything yourself.

Comment: Well if you have the need for two columns this starts to get more complicated. Either create a table type or go with xml. The xml route is incredibly flexible and easy.